# How to plot implicit function $\log_{10}{(xy-1)} = \log_{10}{((1-x)(1-y))}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, graphing-functions

I'm inspecting various function and try to plot their graph based on my observations and compare with graphing tools afterwards.

> Given an implicit function $\log_{10}{(xy-1)} = \log_{10}{((1-x)(1-y))}$ how do i plot it?

This comes really hard to me since I have strong doubts about the domain of the function. I can't just reduce the $\log$ since it comes with some constraints.

Basically what i think is that the above reduces to:

$$
|xy-1|=|(1-x)(1-y)|,
$$
since logarithm argument is greater than $0$ (at least for $x\in \mathbb R$).
But now how do i find the explicit form of $y=f(x)$ considering the constraints implied by the logarithm?

**upd:**

Here is how the graph looks, build based on the answers below:

[image]

Intersection of black an purple areas is the domain of the function, and red line is $y=2-x$. Those parts never cross hence no solution in reals is present. Based on that i conclude that the graph is just an empty plane

Comment: Helps to note that $\log_aX=\log_a Y\implies X=Y$ (and conversely, if $X,Y>0$).

Comment: Your formula involves no absolute value.

Comment: Keep in mind that injectivity for $\log$ is essential to obtain the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given equation implies $xy-1=1-x-y+xy$ i.e. $x+y=2$. For real variables, the maximum obtainable $xy=1-(1-x)^2$ is $1$, i.e. we cannot have $xy>1$. There are therefore no real $x,\,y$ that give both sides of the equation the same finite real value.

Comment: So the graph is just an empty plane, right? Because the only possible solution is on the "edge" of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log x$ is injective and defined for $x>0$ we have

$$\log_{10}{(xy-1)} = \log_{10}{((1-x)(1-y))} \implies xy-1 = (1-x)(1-y) \implies x+y-2=0$$

with the conditions

- $xy-1>0$
- $(1-x)(1-y)>0$